# Multiple possible find-replace in Gvim

Tags: vim, replace

I want to create a command or function to combine multiple finds and replaces. I have tried following command:

```
command MyFR %s/first/1st/g | %s/second/2nd/g | %s/third/3rd/g
```

It works but stops midway if no 'first' or 'second' is found. The error is:

```
E486: Pattern not found: <pattern>
```

How can I make this command work for 'second' and 'third' to be replaced, even if there is no 'first' in text? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the `e` flag to each of your substitution command, which is described in `:h :s_flags`:

```
[e]     When the search pattern fails, do not issue an error message and, in
    particular, continue in maps as if no error occurred.  This is most
    useful to prevent the "No match" error from breaking a mapping.  Vim
    does not suppress the following error messages, however:
        Regular expressions can't be delimited by letters
        \ should be followed by /, ? or &
        No previous substitute regular expression
        Trailing characters
        Interrupted
```

It would give:

```
com! MyFR %s/first/1st/ge | %s/second/2nd/ge | %s/third/3rd/ge
```

---

Another solution would be to merge all substitutions into a single one:

```
com! MyFR %s/\vfirst|second|third/\={'first': '1st', 'second': '2nd', 'third': '3rd'}[tolower(submatch(0))]/g
```

This time, in the replacement part, instead of using a literal string, you would use an expression (see `:h s/\=`). Here, the expression is a given value of a dictionary.

The keys of the dictionary are all your possible matched texts, and the values are their replacements.

The value you retrieve from the dictionary is `tolower(submatch(0))` which evaluates into the matched text (see `:h submatch()`), normalized in its lowercase version (all uppercase characters are turned into their lowercase counterpart through `tolower()`).

Comment: Nice use of a dictionary but it ties you too exact matches doesn't it?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Ah yes, you are right. I forgot about that. I think you could work around this issue by wrapping `submatch()` inside `tolower()` to normalize the matched text, so that the key is always retrieved and there's no `E716` error.